# "Flip" the output of a simple loop using only +1/-1 without if/else

Tags: algorithm, loops, language-agnostic

Suppose I have the following basic loop that outputs integers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    echo i;
}

/* Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 */
```

Is it possible to "flip" its output to `5 4 3 2 1 0` using a simple variable `flag`, whose value can only be `1` or `-1`, without using `if/else`?

Primarily looking for an answer in JavaScript, but this should be a language-independent question.

Comment: what does 'flip the output' even mean?

Comment: @soulcheck read the question!

Comment: @Neal the question is not conclusive. What about printing `abc def ghi`? What's the "flip" of that?

Comment: @YuvalAdam the OP is asking about numbers.

Comment: @Neal question is amiguous to say the least. It can mean anything from reverse iteration to sorting.

Comment: @Neal this is a silly question that has no real answer.

Comment: @Kay are you forgoing ternary operators?

Comment: How about doing `echo (5 - i)` or `echo (flag == 1?i:(5 - i));`

Comment: This sounds more like a [programming puzzle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can calculate the starting point as `5 * (1 - flag) / 2`. You could calculate a value in a similar way to use in the condition for the ending point, but it's easier to always loop the same, and calculate the actual value from the loop variable:

```
start = 5 * (1 - flag) / 2;
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  echo start + i * flag;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry this doesnt work for me

Comment: @ralu: Sorry, got the start values the wrong way around. I adjusted the code.

Comment: This seals it, well done sir!

Answer (score 2):

You need to know range N, because there is no way that you can know how to map 0 -> 5

```
echo ((flag-1)/2)*(-N+1) + (flag*i)
```

Answer (score -4):

Using ternary operators (using flag as true or false):

```
var max_number = 5;
var min_number = 0;
var flag = true;

for(var i = (flag ? min_number : max_number);
    (flag ? i < max_number : i > min_number);
    (flag ? ++i : --i)){

    console.log(i);

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/b26T8/

Comment: Those are essentially `if/else`, but different syntax.

Comment: @SomeKittens the OP never specified about ternary operators.